# Difference between "Typedef declaration" and "Class declaration"

Tags: c++, class, typedef

The question is pretty straightforward. To further clarify, what exactly is the difference between `Foo1` and `Foo2` in the code below in terms of the way they are declared (e.g. one using `class Foo1 { ... };` and the other using `typedef class { ... } Foo2;`)?

```
class Foo1 {
public:
    void bar() { }
};

typedef class {
public:
    void bar() { }
} Foo2;

int main()
{
    Foo1 f1;
    f1.bar();
    Foo2 f2;
    f2.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The differences are: the second one is confusing to C++ programmers, and you cannot instantiate any instances at the declaration.

Comment: @MooingDuck - why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @littleadv: probably because *confusion* is subjective... I know quite a few C++ programmers that would not be confused (some of them even *understand* the difference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is subtle. In the first case you are creating a class with name `Foo1`, while in the second case you are creating an annonymous class and using a `typedef` to provide an aliased name `Foo2`.

The third option would be:

```
typedef class Foo3 {
public:
   void bar() {}
} Foo3;
```

That would create a class named `Foo3` **and** create an alias `Foo3` to refer to it.

The subtleties are in how identifiers are handled in the language. When an identifier is present in the code the compiler will perform lookup to *know* what it means. The lookup will check in each scope, first in the *global identifier space* where most symbols (excluding user defined types) are defined, if it fails to locate the identifier there it will then look in the *user-defined identifier space*. User defined types belong to the second identifier space, while `typedef`-ed names are present in the first group. Only if both lookups fail, the compiler will move on to the next enclosing scope.

To provide a simple test case where the differences are notable:

```
class A {};
typedef class {} B;
typedef class C {} C;
void A();              // correct: no collision
//void B();            // error, identifier B already used with a different meaning!
//void C();            //   "
namespace test {
   void B();
   void C();
   void f() {
      class A a;       // creates variable of type ::A
      A();             // calls function ::A
      B();             // calls function test::B()
      //class B b;     // error: B does not denote a user-defined type name
      C();             // calls function test::C()
      class C c;       // creates variable of type ::C
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are typedefs in the first group?

Comment: @Pubby8: This comes from C. In C, the compiler does not check the user defined types unless the programmer explicitly requests it: `struct A a` would only lookup inside the user defined types, while `A()` will only lookup in the general identifier scope. In C the purpose of `typedef` *is* to create an alias in the *other* identifier space so that you do not need to tell the compiler that you are referring to a type in all usages: `typedef struct A {} A; A a;` will find `A` as the *typedef-ed* name, and users can skip adding the `struct` in front of every use of the type.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas It's a little more subtle in the second case:
"If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the
first typedef-name declared by the declaration to be that class type (or
enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage
purposes only." (§7.1.3/9.  And don't ask me exactly what is meant by
"for linkage purposes only".)

Comment: @JamesKanze: As I understood it some time ago it means that lookup will perform as stated above, but because name mangling needs a name for the type, and the member functions it has to pick up the name of the first typedef. I believe there used to be another corner case around template instantiations, where again the first typedef name will be used to identify what instantiation to trigger `typedef struct {} A; typedef A B; std::vector<B> v1; std::vector<A> v2;` both instantiate the equivalent of `std::vector<A>`, but I thought those were a bit beyond a basic description of what they do...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Your understanding sounds as reasonable as anything else.  But whether the type has a name or not does have some impact: if you don't give it a name (either directly or via typedef), then there are some things you can't do with it, like instantiate a template, or refer to it in a different source.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Right, the first limitation there has been removed in C++11, now local and unnamed types can be used to instantiate templates. But at any rate those are corner cases beyond the question at hand, as in the question the two types have *some* name, either a type name or a typedef'ed name. It is interesting, as always discussing with you I always get the chance to learn something

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the second was necessary for C, but is really unnecessary for C++.  Internally I belive that the second one is creating a unnamed class, and then creating a typedef for that, while the first is just creating the class.

I don't think that the typedef style class declaration is needed in c++ libraries.