# Compilation difference C and C++

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have a piece of code which looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct hostent *server;
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    struct in_addr * address=(in_addr * )server->h_addr;
        fprintf(stderr,"[%d] [%s] server [%s] \n",__LINE__,__func__,inet_ntoa(*address));
}
```

When i use g++ compiler it gets compiled but the same gives the following error with gcc compiler

```
myclient.c: In function ‘main’:
myclient.c:10:31: error: ‘in_addr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
myclient.c:10:31: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
myclient.c:10:41: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `struct in_addr * address=(struct in_addr * )server->h_addr;`

Comment: @Cicada: ahh I got it, but why is g++ is giving is as valid compilation?

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language, why do you even expect it to work out of the box?

Comment: When I go to China and greet people with "Good morning" I get blank looks ... but it works great in South Africa. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to  note that C has multiple namespaces.  The general namespace
includes typedefs and other identifiers, but there is a separate namespace for
structs, enums, and unions tags; another  one for labels, and also each struct
has it's own namespace. In code like this:

```
struct name {
    int name;
} name;
```

`name` means  3 completely different  things and  this is perfectly  legal. To
avoid typing  the `struct` keyword, programmers  often typedef a new  name for
the struct and its tag:

```
typedef struct name {
    int name;
} my_struct;

my_struct s1; /* easier than: struct name s1 */
my_struct s2;
```

In  this last  example name  can even  be omitted,  unless you  want to  use a
pointer to the struct  inside itself. This practice was so  common that in C++
the compiler considers the tag a  defined type  for structs. This is perfectly
legal in C++:

```
struct my_struct {
    int name;
};

my_struct s1;
my_struct s2;
```

And indeed is what's happening in your program. You're using the struct tag as
a type, but it's only a valid type in C++. You have two alternatives:

#### 1.Typedef the struct in its declaration

```
typedef struct in_addr {
    /* ... */
} in_addr;
```

#### 2.Use the `struct` keyword to refer to the struct type

```
(struct in_addr *)
```

The  first one  is not  applicable  since you  didn't declare  the struct.  It
already comes that way. So I'd stick with the second.

Comment: In c++ the two different namespaces still exist and are separate. The difference is in lookup, where for each scope the compiler will first check as in C the general identifier space, and if that fails it will also look in the user defined types identifier space. Check for example: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7970257/36565) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1675446/36565)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I must admit that my C++ knowledge is poor. I edited the answer slightly. Just to confirm: typedef'ed version with the same name for the struct tag and new type is then perfectly valid in C++, right?

Comment: I am not sure about what you exactly mean, but this is ok: `typedef struct A {} B; struct B {};` although confusing. In that context `B` refers to the first type and `struct B` to the second.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I was refering to the "1st alternative" I posted in the answer, more in the lines of `typedef struct A {} A;`. But your comment answered that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `struct in_addr`, not just `in_addr` in `c` code (when casting too).

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
struct in_addr * address=(in_addr * )server->h_addr;
```

to:

```
struct in_addr * address=(struct in_addr * )server->h_addr;
```

Also, C (before C99) only allows variable declarations at the top of a block, and `struct in_addr * address` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ have different rules for struct types; in C++, the keyword `struct` creates a class type where all members are `public` by default.  This type name can stand on its own, unlike in C.

C++ is not merely a superset of C, and there's plenty of code that will compile as one but not the other, or will behave differently because of different semantics.